# How can i decode in java a string generated by javascript using readAsDataURL() and sent by Json?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, json, base64

Im trying to decode a string that was genearated by:

**Javascript code:**

```
fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
```

Ps.: Its a part of encode a file.

After get the file is encoded, i put inside of Json and send to a restfull service using POST method.

**Java code (restfull):**

```
String radiationFilePath = json.getString("radiationFilePath");
String newRadFile = radiationFilePath.replace("\\", ""); \\I read that it is a needed because JsonObject add some '\'
byte[] radiationFileAsBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(newRadFile);
```

Doing that, im receiving an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3a

What should i do?

PS.: Im using Maven to import dependencies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

actually I just had the same issue. here's how I solved it.

**First you don't need to do this** : 
String newRadFile = radiationFilePath.replace("\", "");

**But you have to to this instead** 
String newRadFile = radiationFilePath.split(",")[1]

To solve it I just used **byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(newRadFile)** from **org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64** instead of 
Base64.getDecoder().decode(newRadFile);

Then if you want to create a file from your byte array you can use **FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("test.jpg"), data)** from **org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils**;

hope it helps,
Adrien.

Comment: If the file has more than 100kb, the file content is not according with original file... Why it happend?